# unable to create rds table in lambda function

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have the code below in a Lambda Function. The connection occurs fine but I am unable to create the database as the output is:

"Table not created!"

Let me know if you see anything wrong!

```
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_endpoint, user=username, password=password, database=db_name)
    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        print("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")

    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("create table if not exists audiofiles ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)), length varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)), timestamp varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)), location varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))")
        conn.commit()
    except:
        return 'Table not created!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's something wrong with that create table statement. Let's isolate it from the Python code and format it on multiple lines:

```
create table if not exists audiofiles ( 
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)), 
  length varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)), 
  timestamp varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)), 
  location varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

This is nonsense. It repeats the PRIMARY KEY three extra times, with extra closing parentheses.

When you catch an exception, you should at least examine the Error you caught, so you understand something about the type of error. Looking at the error message will help you understand the cause. Examples are shown here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
> length varchar(255) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (id)),
> timestamp' at line 4

Syntax errors tell you exactly where the SQL parser got confused. It didn't know what to do from the point it saw `length`, because by the syntax you provided, you had closed the parentheses and there should be no more columns defined after that.

You can also try testing the SQL syntax on a local MySQL instance, or on a site like https://dbfiddle.uk. This will also give you a more informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your create

When youtry your query in Mysql Workbench or so you will find the errors quickly

So use

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("create table if not exists audiofiles ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255) NOT NULL, length varchar(255) NOT NULL, timestamp varchar(255) NOT NULL, location varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))")
    conn.commit()
```